# Where is the source pages for MoinMoin HelpOn pages?

Tags: wiki, moinmoin

Setting up MoinMoin 1.9.2 on my Fedora 13 laptop, I had to download the moinmoin 1.9.3 installation tar file to add static contents that the Fedora packages did not include.  What I am missing are all the HelpContent & HelpOn* pages.

These Wiki Pages were not in the moin-1.9.3.tar.gz

Does anyone know how to obtain the HelpOn pages for MoinMoin Wiki?

My installation started with an installed package and copying files to another directory.  Is it possible that something is missing because no "setup" script was run?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up the page(s) in your desired language and declare your language in the config file, which is essentially step (3) of the quick install (i.e., http://localhost:8080/LanguageSetup).

- Have look at the docs/INSTALL.HTML file.
- Set up your language via http://localhost:8080/LanguageSetup
- Make sure the HelpOn pages are installed in /wiki/underlay/pages

The following might be additional useful pointers in case you want more info about this:

- http://moinmo.in/LanguageSetup
- http://moinmo.in/FranklinPiat/LanguageSetup